# UIKit bug? viewWillAppear not called when it should be

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uikit

https://github.com/trapper-/unballanced

I've found a bug in a project I'm working on and pulled it out into a simple example linked above. I think this is probably a UIKit bug.

Basically VC1 is inside a containerVC, then VC2 is presented modally in current context (so it is also contained) then VC3 is presented modally full screen. Now when we dismiss back our way back to VC1 there will be a missing viewWillAppear for VC1. This also causes a console warning.

`Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <ViewController1: 0x7f9c5970afc0>`

This is what you will see in console.

While presenting

```
ViewController1 viewWillAppear
ViewController1 viewDidAppear
ViewController1 viewWillDisappear
ViewController2 viewWillAppear
ViewController2 viewDidAppear
ViewController1 viewDidDisappear
ViewController2 viewWillDisappear
ViewController3 viewWillAppear
ViewController3 viewDidAppear
ViewController2 viewDidDisappear
```

While dismissing

```
ViewController3 viewWillDisappear
ViewController2 viewWillAppear
ViewController2 viewDidAppear
ViewController3 viewDidDisappear
ViewController2 viewWillDisappear
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <ViewController1: 0x7f9c5970afc0>.
ViewController1 viewDidAppear
ViewController2 viewDidDisappear
```

You can see the missing `ViewController1 viewWillAppear` and the `Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions` message instead.

Any solution to this issue?

Comment: Might be treading issue. Try using GCD delay action

Comment: How is this question off topic? I have the 'Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example' linked on github.

Comment: I felt the same issue before one year, In my case, during push and pop animation this message (Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <ViewController1: 0x7f9c5970afc0>) appeared, during that time i faced some wired behaviour. At last i fixed with GCD delay function. U have one more option too. Stop push and pop animation. This may be the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an iOS bug. Not sure if it helps in your real app, but changing from `Current Context` to `Over Current Context` on your VC2 presentation actually works and visually looks the same as far as I can see.

The docs seems to indicate that `Over Current Context` is an alternative to `UIModalPresentationFullScreen`, however it is also clearly using the current context, so I think the real difference in your case will only be that VC1 is not removed after VC2 has been presented.

> When presenting a view controller using the
>   UIModalPresentationFullScreen style, UIKit normally removes the views
>   of the underlying view controller after the transition animations
>   finish. You can prevent the removal of those views by specifying the
>   UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext style instead. You might use
>   that style when the presented view controller has transparent areas
>   that let underlying content show through.

[Docs on View Controller Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html)